# Showing record(s) from DB in a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, datagridview

Again, I have an Access DB connected to the form using C#.
The code works ( seems so ) but it shows only the first record of the DB, nothing more in the gridview.

```
string connetionString;
        OleDbConnection connection;
        OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string Sql;

        connetionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Z:\Tempesta\Area Progetto\Area_Progetto_DATA_MAGAZINE\Data_Magazine\Data_Magazine\DB\DataMG.mdb;";
        connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
        Sql = "select * from Prodotti";
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, connection);
            oledbAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: You code has not any problem, check your file path and database table record.

Comment: I can insert records in my DB but not all records are shown in the gridview, just the first one plus the file path is correct ( otherwise it wouldnt run ) and the table record is fine

Comment: Check the RowCount property on the Grid. Is it set to 1 or what ??

Comment: Cant find that RowCount property, whats that?

Comment: Its there in dataTable.Rowcount (Just to confirm you get all rows)... Okay apart from it do u have any event of datagridview which is fired when you bind your grid ?

Comment: Actually, it starts with the Load of the form. `private void VisualizzaArticoli_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: dataGridView1.databind();   try to add this.

Comment: Visual Studio doesnt find the function " databind "

Comment: your problem is showing record or inserting record?